# Custom template doesn't visiable in the template suffix section in shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have added a new custom template like `page.about.liquid` in the template folder. But this template is not visible on `Template suffix` section. screenshot attached below. Can anybody help me here?
https://www.screencast.com/t/hJGH3VzN

https://www.screencast.com/t/PLdBPiuYp

```
{% include 'page-header', title: 'About Us' %}

<section class="about section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="{{settings.about_img | img_url: '1920x'}}">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        {{page.content}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Shopify documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/store/create-alternate-templates), only templates present in your **published** theme will be available in the Theme templates section.

> The Theme templates section won't appear on the corresponding page
>   unless your theme has more than one template. If you don't see the
>   Theme templates section after creating a new template, it's possible
>   that you have created a template of a different type. For example, you
>   might have created a page template instead of a product template.
>
> **Only templates present in your published theme will be available in
>   the Theme templates section.**